# Python Error handling in try block pass entry to array

Tags: python, arrays, exception, error-handling, openssl

I am ingesting a list of servers from a text file and using pyopenssl to resolve, connect,and retrieve the SSL Certificate information and passing my results to an array. It is working perfectly until one of my servers in the list does not resolve and I get a socket.gaierror error.

Although I can capture the error in the logs I am trying pass along something that will note the exception in my array results and that I will be able to pass to a table and send in an email. I want it to note in the host field "Unable to resolve" Can anyone point me towards a good way of accomplishing that? Thanks!
Basic order of operations:

1. Grab each host in the file
2. Create an array to house the results
3. Connect to server using SSL
4. Get SSL info and close connection
5. From SSL certificate get host name, expiration date, and decode
6. Get date, format, and calculate number of days until SSL expires
7. Record entry in the ssl_results array

   ```
    import ssl
    from datetime import datetime
    import OpenSSL
    import socket
    from datetime import timedelta
    import datetime
    import traceback
    import logging

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:% (message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/SSLNag.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    try:
        ipfile = open('server_ip.txt')
        cur_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        ssl_results = {}
   except Exception as e:
       logger.warning("ERROR ENCOUNTERED! \n\n")
       logger.warning(str(traceback.format_exc()))
   for ip in ipfile:
       ssl_results[str(ip)] = {'host': '', 'server_name': '',
                     'exp_date': '', 'days_to_expire': ''}
       try:
       host = ip.strip().split(':')[0]
       port = ip.strip().split(':')[1]
       print('\nChecking certificate for server ', host)
       ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
       s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       s.connect((host, int(port)))
       cnx = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
       cnx.set_connect_state()
       cnx.do_handshake()
       cert = cnx.get_peer_certificate()
       s.close()
       server_name = cert.get_subject().commonName
       print(server_name)
       edate = cert.get_notAfter()
       edate = edate.decode()
       exp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(edate, '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
       days_to_expire = int((exp_date - cur_date).days)
       print(exp_date)
       print('day to expire', days_to_expire)
       ssl_results[str(ip)]['host'] = host
       ssl_results[str(ip)]['server_name'] = server_name
       ssl_results[str(ip)]['exp_date'] = exp_date
       ssl_results[str(ip)]['days_to_expire'] = days_to_expire
    except Exception as e:
       logger.warning('Error on connection to Server,', str(ip))
       logger.warning("ERROR ENCOUNTERED", host, "\n\n")
       logger.warning(str(traceback.format_exc()))
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add an exception for the socket.gaierror and update the array.

```
except socket.gaierror as e:
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['host'] = host
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['server_name'] = "Could not connect"
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['exp_date'] = 0
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['days_to_expire'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

first theres an Indent missing at the second try and except :-)

Isnt it just this simple:

```
 import ssl
 from datetime import datetime
 import OpenSSL
 import socket
 from datetime import timedelta
 import datetime
 import traceback
 import logging

 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
 formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:% (message)s')
 file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/SSLNag.log')
 file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
 logger.addHandler(file_handler)

 try:
     ipfile = open('server_ip.txt')
     cur_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
     ssl_results = {}
except Exception as e:
    logger.warning("ERROR ENCOUNTERED! \n\n")
    logger.warning(str(traceback.format_exc()))
for ip in ipfile:
    global server_name, host, exp_date, days_to expire
    ssl_results[str(ip)] = {'host': '', 'server_name': '',
                  'exp_date': '', 'days_to_expire': ''}
    try:
    host = ip.strip().split(':')[0]
    port = ip.strip().split(':')[1]
    print('\nChecking certificate for server ', host)
    ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, int(port)))
    cnx = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
    cnx.set_connect_state()
    cnx.do_handshake()
    cert = cnx.get_peer_certificate()
    s.close()
    server_name = cert.get_subject().commonName
    print(server_name)
    edate = cert.get_notAfter()
    edate = edate.decode()
    exp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(edate, '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
    days_to_expire = int((exp_date - cur_date).days)
    print(exp_date)
    print('day to expire', days_to_expire)
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['host'] = host
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['server_name'] = server_name
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['exp_date'] = exp_date
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['days_to_expire'] = days_to_expire
 except Exception as e:
    logger.warning('Error on connection to Server,', str(ip))
    logger.warning("ERROR ENCOUNTERED", host, "\n\n")
    logger.warning(str(traceback.format_exc()))
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['host'] = "Unable to resolve"
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['server_name'] = " "
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['exp_date'] = " "
    ssl_results[str(ip)]['days_to_expire'] = " "
```

Or what to you want to accomplish?
Do you also want the email client?
Try this:https://realpython.com/python-send-email/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Usus. I am not sure why the formatting is off. It is fine in the preview but when I post it doesn't translate but maybe I am doing something wrong. My main issue is trying to pass "Unable to connect" to the ssl_results array when a host does not respond.

Comment: Does this conclue this Question?

Comment: No I still have the issue that I posted which is trying to pass "Unable to connect" to the ssl_results array when a host does not respond. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify Thy!